# Report which shows all products and its attributes, features and categories it belongs to

Tags: mysql, prestashop

I am trying to build a report which shows all products and its attributes, features and categories it belongs to. But query i wrote is taking lot of time. how do i improve this ?

```
[CODE]

SELECT   max(if((ps_attribute_group_lang.name like "Color"),ps_attribute_lang.name,'')) AS Color, max(if((ps_attribute_group_lang.name like "Size"),ps_attribute_lang.name,'')) AS Size, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Brand"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Brand, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Sub brand"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Subbrand, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Occasion"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Occasion, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Sleeves"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Sleeves, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Cuffs"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Cuffs, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Collar"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Collar, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Neck"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Neck, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Hood"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Hood, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Shoulder"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Shoulder, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Straps"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Straps, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Trouser Front"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS TrouserFront, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Front Opening"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS FrontOpening, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Suit Front"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS SuitFront, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Fit"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Fit, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Wash"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Wash, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Length"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Length, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Style"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Style, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Pattern"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Pattern, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Weatherproof"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Weatherproof, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Fabric Type"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS FabricType, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Suit Type"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS SuitType, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Accessories"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Accessories, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Fashion Accessories"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS FashionAccessories, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Shoe Type"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS ShoeType, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Bag Type"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS BagType, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Material"),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS Material, max(if((ps_feature_lang.name like "Ethnic Bottom Style "),ps_feature_value_lang.value,'')) AS EthnicBottomStyle,  ps_product_attribute.id_product AS productid,
`ps_product_lang`.`name` AS `productname`,
`ps_product_attribute`.`ean13`         AS `a_ean13`,
`ps_category_lang`.`name`              AS `categoryname`,
`ps_product_attribute`.`id_product_attribute`  AS `id_product_attribute`,
`t_vendorproducts`.`a_vendorid`        AS `vendorid`,
round(`ps_product`.`price`,2)  AS price   from
        (((((((`ps_product_attribute`
        join `ps_product_lang`          ON ((`ps_product_lang`.`id_product` = `ps_product_attribute`.`id_product`)))
        join `ps_product_attribute_combination` ON ((`ps_product_attribute_combination`.`id_product_attribute` = `ps_product_attribute`.`id_product_attribute`)))
        join `ps_attribute`            ON ((`ps_attribute`.`id_attribute` = `ps_product_attribute_combination`.`id_attribute`)))
        join `ps_attribute_lang`        ON ((`ps_attribute_lang`.`id_attribute` = `ps_product_attribute_combination`.`id_attribute`)))
        join `ps_attribute_group_lang`   ON (((`ps_attribute`.`id_attribute_group` = `ps_attribute_group_lang`.`id_attribute_group`))))))
        join  ps_feature_product        on ps_feature_product.id_product = ps_product_attribute.id_product
    join  ps_feature_value_lang      on ps_feature_value_lang.id_feature_value = ps_feature_product.id_feature_value
        join  ps_feature_lang           on ps_feature_product.id_feature = ps_feature_lang.id_feature
        join  ps_product               on ps_product.id_product = ps_product_attribute.id_product
    join  ps_category  cate1       on cate1.id_category = ps_product.id_category_default
    join  ps_category  cate2       on cate2.id_category = cate1.id_parent
    join  ps_category_lang        on ps_category_lang.id_category = cate1.id_category
   WHERE  ps_product_lang.id_shop = 1  GROUP BY ps_product_attribute.ean13 ORDER BY productid

[/CODE]
```

Here is what explain is telling

```
"id"    "select_type"   "table" "type"  "possible_keys" "key"   "key_len"   "ref"   "rows"  "Extra"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "ps_product"    "index" "PRIMARY"   "id_category_default"   "5" \N  "5481"  "Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "pa"    "ref"   "product_attribute_product,product_default" "product_attribute_product" "4" "mycode.ps_product.id_product"  "2" "Using index"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "pac"   "ref"   "id_product_attribute"  "id_product_attribute"  "4" "mycode.pa.id_product_attribute"    "1" "Using index"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "a" "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "mycode.pac.id_attribute"   "1" ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "ag"    "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "mycode.a.id_attribute_group"   "1" "Using index"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "al"    "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY,id_lang"   "PRIMARY"   "8" "mycode.a.id_attribute,const"   "1" ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "agl"   "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "8" "mycode.ag.id_attribute_group,const"    "1" ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "ps_feature_product"    "ref"   "id_product"    "id_product"    "4" "mycode.pa.id_product"  "1" ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "ps_feature_value_lang" "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY,ps_feature_value_lang_lang"    "PRIMARY"   "8" "mycode.ps_feature_product.id_feature_value,const"  "1" ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "ps_feature_lang"   "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY,id_lang"   "PRIMARY"   "8" "mycode.ps_feature_product.id_feature,const"    "1" ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "cate1" "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "mycode.ps_product.id_category_default" "1" ""
"1" "SIMPLE"    "cate2" "eq_ref"    "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "mycode.cate1.id_parent"    "1" "Using index"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "ps_category_lang"  "ref"   "PRIMARY,ps_category_lang_ID_CATEGORY"  "ps_category_lang_ID_CATEGORY"  "4" "mycode.cate1.id_category"  "2" "Using index"
"1" "SIMPLE"    "ps_product_lang"   "ref"   "PRIMARY"   "PRIMARY"   "4" "mycode.ps_product.id_product"  "3" "Using index"
```

Comment: Hm, no thanks - but good luck anyway. Oh, OK - two things 1) use '=' for equality comparisons. use 'like' for 'similar' comparisons. 2) to dtand any chance of getting further help with this, you will need to provide an EXPLAIN

Comment: Your database's config variables aren't optimal, you should increase innodb_buffer_pool variable to a larger value.

Comment: Good. Another thing - why do you ROUND() price? Are prices stored at a greater precision than 0.00?